# How to get rid of blocks nested too deeply while using jshint with grunt?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Some one please help me to fix a warning in grunt.
I am using fallowing condition in my project and i am getting a warning,
Blocks are nested too deeply<5>.

```
var chartGuideLines = function() {
    var chartid = $scope.chart.panel.id;
    var chartTitle = $scope.confdata.prop.chartsarray;
    for(var i = 0; i< chartTitle.length; i++) {
        var chartslength = chartTitle[i];
        var chartsId = chartslength.id;
        if(chartsId === chartid){
            for(var j = 0; j < chartslength.charts.length; j++) {
                var chartsdata = chartslength.charts[j];
                var guidlines = chartsdata.guideliney;
                if( typeof guidlines !== 'undefined') {
                    var guidlineY = $scope.chart.targetNode.getElementsByClassName('guideline-y');
                    for (var ii=0; ii<guidlineY.length; ii++) {
                        guidlineY[ii].style.strokeDasharray = guidlines.stroke;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a warning. Is this really a problem for you?  While certainly there is a "code smell" when you have things nested this deeply to hint that some refactoring may be in order, in your case and without understanding what the code it intended to do, it would seem difficult to refactor the triple-nested loop in a logical way.

Comment: @Mike Brant, It's not a problem i can do --force but just to know any option to use reduce loops .

Comment: You could do something like break each level of those loops into a separate function call, but again, in your case I think that would actually make the code harder to understand/maintain.

Answer (score 10):

just add following sentence before function starts.

// jshint maxdepth:5